# How to download data as Excel (.xslx) in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, excel, next.js

I want to add a "Download as Excel" button to my Nextj application, by using any library to simplify the development or adding a component to my project; I already tried these but had issues with both of them:

> 1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-table-to-excel

This Downloads data with '.xls' file extension so opening them with excel throws a warning. I tried to edit the source code and change file extension to '.xlsx' but this makes the output file corrupted.

[image]

> 2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-export-excel

this works fine with react-create-app but can't make it work in Nextjs due to it's custom webpack configuration. I can't make this part working in Nextjs

```
///webpack.config.js
vendor: [
        .....
        'xlsx',
        'file-saver'
],
.....
node: {fs: 'empty'},
externals: [
    {'./cptable': 'var cptable'},
    {'./jszip': 'jszip'}
 ]
```

Thanks in advance for any guide!

Comment: Hey. Did you find a solution to this? I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

here is my code as a a sample i hope it helps

`/api/shipments/downloadManifest.js/`

```js
const fs = require("fs");
import Shipment from "../../../backend/shipmentModel";
const json2xls = require("json2xls");
import path from "path";

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { batchStart, batchEnd } = req.body;
    if (!batchStart || !batchEnd) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        status: "error",
        error: "No start and end date defined!",
      });
    }

    try {
      const data = await Shipment.find({
        createdAt: {
          $gte: batchStart,
          $lte: batchEnd,
        },
      });

      const excel = json2xls(data, {
        fields: [
          "name",
          "destination",
          "weight",
          "carton",
          "dollar_rate",
          "customs_rate",
          "freight_rate",
          "freight_$",
          "freight",
          "customs",
          "amountDue",
          "mobile",
          "action",
        ],
      });

      await fs.writeFileSync("./public/manifest.xlsx", excel, "binary");
      const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), "/public/manifest.xlsx");
      const manifestBuffer = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

      await new Promise(function (resolve) {
        res.setHeader(
          "Content-Disposition",
          "attachment; filename=manifest.xlsx"
        );
        res.setHeader(
          "Content-Type",
          "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        );
        res.setHeader("Content-Length", `${manifestBuffer.size}`);
        manifestBuffer.pipe(res);
        manifestBuffer.on("end", resolve);
        manifestBuffer.on("error", function (err) {
          if (err.code === "ENOENT") {
            res.status(400).json({
              error: "error",
              error: "Sorry we could not find the file you requested!",
            });
            res.end();
          } else {
            res.status(500).json({
              error: "error",
              message: "Sorry, something went wrong!",
            });
            res.end();
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(200).json({
        status: "error",
        msg: error.message,
      });
    }
  }
};

export default handler;
```

`/pages/shipments.js`

```js
 setLoading(true);
    const data = await axios.post(
      "/api/shipments/downloadManifest",
      {
        batchStart: batch.batchStart,
        batchEnd:
          batchIndex ===
          batches?.[batches?.length - 1]?.months?.[
            batches?.[batches?.length - 1]?.months?.length - 1
          ]?.batches?.length -
            1
            ? new Date(Date.now())
            : batch.batchEnd,
      },
      {
        responseType: "blob",
      }
    );
    const pdfBlob = new Blob([data.data], { type: "application/xlsx" });
    setLoading(false);

    return saveAs(pdfBlob, "manifest.xlsx");
```

do not forget to install `"file-saver" and "json2xls" npm packages` as a dependency

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).